# Как сформировать запрос(ы) из ссылки(ок) к форме с вызовом выбранной по клику option в select?

Tags: javascript, html

Исходные данные:
на одной странице длинный список ссылок.
Страница A

```
<ul>
<li><a href="register#registerCard"  onClick="registerCard.value='Img10001'">Вариант 1</a></li>
<li><a href="register#registerCard"  onClick="registerCard.value='Img10002'">Вариант 2</a></li>
...
<li><a href="register#registerCard"  onClick="registerCard.value='Img1000N'">Вариант N</a></li>
</ul>
```

Страница B = register
На другой странице форма с селектом и выбором опций.

```
<form name="registerCard" id="registerCard">
...
<select name="registerCard" id="registerCard">
<option value="Img10001">Вариант 1</option>
<option value="Img10001">Вариант 2</option>
...
<option value="Img1000N">Вариант N</option>
</select>
</form>
```

Вопрос:
Не удается завязать по клику по определенной ссылке в списке на странице A ( * .php) > вызов страницы B (register.php) с выбором нужной опции в списке select > option. Как это оптимально решить (желательно без лишнего JS), допустим с data-value или иначе.

Как вариант > использовать запросы типа GET > register.php #registerCard?select=Img10003

Почему не отрабатывают такие GET запросы при обращении к форме заявки? В форме указан метод POST для отправки заявок в итоге.

Полагаю метод GET не подойдет, т.к. форма работает с методом POST.
Значит лучше использовать передачу данных с помощью data-value > в форму.
Вопрос как это правильно организовать между страницами поиска и формы с выбором option в select выше означенной формы заявки.

Answer (score 0):

JS:

```
onClick="document.getElementById('registerCard').value='Img10001'
```

JQuery:

```
onClick="$('#registerCard').value='Img10001'
```

Answer (score 0):

Без лишнего JS:

Во-первых смотрите принцип (где POST, где GET):
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Можно вообще `<a href="register.php?select=Img10003">`.

Часть после `#` на сервер не идет.

Обращение GET к `register.php` формирует хтмл с формой.
При формировании можно смотреть selected из `$_GET`.

Метод у формы -- POST, т. к. регистрация -- действие.

`action` может быть любой, например `do-register.php`.

Обработчик POST-а проведет регистрацию и средиректит дальше.

Если POST обрабатывает тот же `register.php`,
то можно проверять `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` в самом начале.

---

А вообще, такое время, на JS поглядывать лучше, а то лишним ...